# Wordpress Redirection Error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm currently using Wordpress 4.8 with permalink structure of https://www.example.com/%category%/%postname%/. I also use [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin. After awhile, I decided to move my wordpress installation from Root to Subdirectory using this [tutorial from official wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). I followed exactly like first method. It works but from time to time I receive a lot of 404 error log in Redirection plugin log and Google Search Console log.

I created subdirectory for wordpress using **same name** with domain name. Assume my domain is https://www.example.com. I created subdirectory name of *www.example.com*. Reason because I have multiple addon domains which I installed wordpress in similar way. Only this main domain have problem.

**PROBLEM:**
I often receive 404 errors log in Redirection plugin log and Google Search Console. Assume I have a page of **overflow** then my URL error look like this https://www.example.com/www.example.com/category/overflow/ instead of https://www.example.com/category/overflow/ and this is happened everyday on many URL's even newer posts. With exception of my index.php where my https://www.example.com/www.example.com/index.php always redirect to https://www.example.com/ without any problem and no error logs.

**.HTACCESS on Root**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www.example.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.example.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www.example.com/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**.HTACCESS on Subdirectory**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**QUESTION:**
How do I add a wildcard redirects which will redirect anything matching condition **www.example.com/www.example.com** to **www.example.com**

For example:

1. https://www.example.com/www.example.com/pageA/ to https://www.example.com/pageA/
2. https://www.example.com/www.example.com/Category1/pageB/ to https://www.example.com/Category1/pageB/
3. https://www.example.com/www.example.com/Category2/pageC/ to https://www.example.com/Category2/pageC/ and so on.

I'll be honest. I do know how to redirect oldPage to newPage but seems this is out of my knowledge. I tried many tutorial on google and redirect generator etc but still I receive 404 error logs of that kind. Please help me. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this plugin [301 redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/). it is useful to redirection old URL to new URL